# Which is the best way to get a list of running processes in unix with python?

Tags: python

I'm trying:

```
import commands
print commands.getoutput("ps -u 0")
```

But it doesn't work on os x.
os instead of commands gives the same output:
USER   PID %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND

nothing more

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works on Mac OS X 10.5.5.  Note the capital **-U** option.  Perhaps that's been your problem.

```
import subprocess
ps = subprocess.Popen("ps -U 0", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print ps.stdout.read()
ps.stdout.close()
ps.wait()
```

Here's the Python version

```
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Feb 22 2008, 07:57:53) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5363)] on darwin
```

Comment: This isn't going to be very cross-platform.  ps options on Linux/Unix are going to be different, and not exist at all on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

If the OS support the /proc fs you can do:

```
>>> import os
>>> pids = [int(x) for x in os.listdir('/proc') if x.isdigit()]
>>> pids
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, ... 9406, 9414, 9428, 9444]
>>>
```

A cross-platform solution (linux, freebsd, osx, windows) is by using [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/):

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.pids()
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, ... 9406, 9414, 9428, 9444]    
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

The cross-platform replacement for `commands` is `subprocess`. See the [subprocess module documentation](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-subprocess.html). The 'Replacing older modules' section includes [how to get output from a command](http://docs.python.org/lib/node534.html).

Of course, you still have to pass the right arguments to 'ps' for the platform you're on. Python can't help you with that, and though I've seen occasional mention of third-party libraries that try to do this, they usually only work on a few systems (like strictly SysV style, strictly BSD style, or just systems with /proc.)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried in on OS X (10.5.5) and seems to work just fine:

```
print commands.getoutput("ps -u 0")

UID   PID TTY           TIME CMD
0     1 ??         0:01.62 /sbin/launchd
0    10 ??         0:00.57 /usr/libexec/kextd
```

etc.

Python 2.5.1

Answer (score 1):

any of the above python calls - but try 'pgrep

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use os instead of commands:

```
import os
print os.system("ps -u 0")
```

Comment: os.system() doesn't give you the output, the output is just printed to the screen. os.system() returns the process exit status, which you'll see as a trailing '0' in the output.