# Python library for Linux process management

Tags: python, linux, process

Through my web interface I would like to start/stop certain processes and determine whether a started process is still running.

My existing website is Python based and running on a Linux server, so do you know of a suitable library that supports this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To start/stop python sub processes you can use the subprocess module.
To check whether they are running you might use [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil):

```
>>> import psutil
>>> pid = 1034  # some pid
>>> psutil.pid_exists(pid)
True
>>>
```

...or this (it will also check if the PID has been reused):

```
>>> p = psutil.Process(pid)
>>> p.is_running()
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

Checking the list of running processes is accomplished (even by core utilities like "ps") by looking at the contents of the /proc directory.

As such, the library you're interested for querying running processes is the same as used for working with any other files and directories (i.e. `sys` or `os`, depending on the flavor you're after. Pay special attention to `os.path` though, it does most of what you're after). To terminate or otherwise interact with processes, you send them signals, which is accomplished with `os.kill`. Finally, you start new processes using  `os.popen` and friends.

Answer (score 3):

Since you said this is a Linux server, calling the external *ps* binary is usually slower, uses more resources and is more error prone than using the information from */proc* directly.

Since nobody else mentioned, one simple way is:

```
glob.glob('/proc/[0-9]*/')
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This is what i use. It uses procfs (so you are limited to Unix like systems, will not work on macs i think) and the previously mentioned glob. It also gets the cmdline, which allows you to identify the process. For killing the process you can use `os.kill(signal.SIGTERM, pid)`. For using subprocess, please check this post [Python, Popen and select - waiting for a process to terminate or a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337863/python-popen-and-select-waiting-for-a-process-to-terminate-or-a-timeout/1035488#1035488)

```
def list_processes():
    """
    This function will return an iterator with the process pid/cmdline tuple

    :return: pid, cmdline tuple via iterator
    :rtype: iterator

    >>> for procs in list_processes():
    >>>     print procs
    ('5593', '/usr/lib/mozilla/kmozillahelper')
    ('6353', 'pickup -l -t fifo -u')
    ('6640', 'kdeinit4: konsole [kdeinit]')
    ('6643', '/bin/bash')
    ('7451', '/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ipython')
    """
    for pid_path in glob.glob('/proc/[0-9]*/'):

        # cmdline represents the command whith which the process was started
        f = open("%s/cmdline" % pid_path)
        pid = pid_path.split("/")[2] # get the PID
        # we replace the \x00 to spaces to make a prettier output from kernel
        cmdline = f.read().replace("\x00", " ").rstrip()
        f.close()

        yield (pid, cmdline)
```

Answer (score 1):

The os module is probably your friend. There's `os.kill`, for instance to kill a process.

In terms of getting a list of processes, you'll probably want to shell out to the `ps` command. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160245) has more information on that.

Comment: yeah I am ideally after a higher level library than manually parsing ps

Comment: Running the `ps` command inside a shell is a lot more dangerous than tylerl's note about using /proc. Do that instead.

Comment: because it's bad practice that leads to worse practice. First you run the `ps` command. Then you figure you want to pass a few switches to it. Then maybe a user-supplied filter string, and then you have a rooted webserver. Also, it encourages using `kill` which has the same problem.

Comment: Not sure about "encourages using kill" because there's os.kill, which means you should never have to shell out to the actual "kill" command. However, the /proc idea is definitely better than shelling out to ps, and I recommend doing that instead of my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Python subprocess http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html might help you. If you create a process with subprocess, you can use Popen.terminate() function to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use PSutil. To provide a practical example:

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.get_process_list():
    if proc.username == 'yourusername':
        if myappname in proc.cmdline:
            print 'App is running'
```

Alternatively, Red Hat use and maintain a Python module called **python-linux-procfs** , which natively parses /proc, to manage processes. it's not very well publicized, but provides some additional Linux-specific features (eg, scheduling class) which are sometimes useful.

http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/gitweb/?p=python-linux-procfs.git

Answer (score 0):

Explore [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) which is a Python based process control system for Linux. It gives a web based UI to check  the process status/start/stop/restart automatically on crash.
Also there are [superlance](https://superlance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crashmail.html) plugins available  where you can send mail in case of process crash.