# Trouble in ending task using Python

Tags: python, windows-8, cmd

I know that in windows cmd I can type the following text to end a process:

```
taskkill/im chrome.exe /f
```

But how can I do it using Python?

I've tried this:

```
from subprocess import *
call("taskkill/im chrome.exe /f", shell=True)
```

But it showed this:

```
'taskkill' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

So what's wrong with my code? How can I make it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to kill a process on Windows from within Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278847/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-process-on-windows-from-within-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

os.system("taskkill/im chrome.exe /f")
```

I don't have access to a machine with windows here, but it should work.

Edit:

Try also:

1- The command needed a white space between taskkill and /IM, so:

```
 os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
```

2- [Taskkill is not in Windows XP, there ais a less powerfull tool called tskill](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/taskkill-is-not-recognized-as-command/20416.html%29) so:

```
os.system("tskill chrome")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the same problem occured again. :(

Comment: Oh, I don't know why but both of the two method didn't work. They just showed 'taskkill'(or tskill) is not recognized as...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question linked to by RvdK, above: you need a fully-qualified path to taskkill.exe, but not mentioned was the fact that you need to remember to escape the backslashes, so

`call("c:\\windows\\system32\\taskkill.exe /im chrome.exe /f", shell=True)`

Should work (it does on my Win7 machine).

Note that you don't actually *need* the `shell=True` bit, as mentioned in the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) docs:

> On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies
>   the default shell. The only time you need to specify shell=True on
>   Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the
>   shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch
>   file or console-based executable.

So `call("c:\\windows\\system32\\taskkill.exe /im chrome.exe /f")` Is better.

Answer (score 0):

#my memo

```
from win32com.client import GetObject
import os

WMI = GetObject('winmgmts:')
for p in WMI.ExecQuery('select * from Win32_Process where Name LIKE "%chrome%"'):
    os.system("taskkill /F /PID "+str(p.ProcessId))
```