# Function attributes in Python

Tags: python, django, apache, concurrency, mod-wsgi

I asked this question as continuation of [Limit function execution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507359/limit-function-execution-in-python)

I found a way to do it without threads etc. Just simple checking from time to time.

Here is my decorator:

```
def time_limit(seconds):
    def decorator(func):
        func.info = threading.local()

        def check_timeout():
            if hasattr(func.info, 'end_time'):
                if time.time() > func.info.end_time:
                    raise TimeoutException

        func.check_timeout = check_timeout

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if not hasattr(func.info, 'end_time'):
                func.info.end_time = time.time() + seconds
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

And usage:

```
@time_limit(60)
def algo():
  do_something()
  algo.check_timeout()
  do_something_else()
```

It works fine on localhost, but it fails on server apache with mod_wsgi and django.

1. First problem. Notice `hasattr`? I should add it, because from time to time I got error `'_thread.local'` has no attribute `end_time`
2. Why do I need threading.local? As @Graham Dumpleton pointed out, we can't have a single global end time as a subsequent request will come in and overwrite it. So if the first request hadn't finished, its `end_time` would get reset to whatever was set for the later request.
   The problem is that this approach doesn't help. Suppose I have following session of runs.

First run - before timeout occurs - runs perfectly

Second run - before timeout occurs - runs perfectly

Third run - timeout occurs - raises `TimeoutException`

All subsequent calls raise `TimeoutException` no matter was it or not.

It seems like all subsequent calls look at end_time copy of third run, and since there is Timeout, they also raise `Timeout`.

How can I localize end_time for each function call? Thank you.

EDIT:
Thanks to @miki725 and @Antti Haapala I simplified my function and made it a simple class:

```
class TimeLimit(object):
    def __init__(self, timeout=60):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.end = None

    def check_timeout(self):
        if self.end and time.time() > self.end:
            raise TimeoutException
        else:
            self.start()

    def start(self):
        if not self.end:
            self.end = time.time() + self.timeout
```

However, it is very inconvenient for me to pass timer to function, because algo is actually very complex recursive function.
So, I did following:

```
timer = TimeLimit() # fails. I think because it is global
def algo()
  do_stuff()
  timer.check_timeout()
  do_another_stuff()
  sub_algo() # check inside it to
  algo()
  ...
```

Is there any way to make `timer` thread-safe. Is pseudoprivate `_timer` of any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding `end_time` on the function object itself. Since each thread will import all of the Python modules, effectively you will only set `end_time` `n` times as number of threads you are running (which seems to be in your case 2).

To solve this you can either always set `end_time` in each thread, however that does not seem elegant to me since you are making a couple of assumptions about what will be executed.

Other solution is to use classes. That will allow to keep state in a class instance and hence this issue will not occur.

```
class ExecuteWithTimeout(object):
    def __init__(self, to_execute, timeout):
        self.to_execute = to_execute
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.end = None

    def check_timeout(self):
        if time.time() > self.end:
            raise TimeoutException

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.end = time.time() + self.timeout
        result = self.to_execute(*args, **kwargs)
        self.check_timeout()
        return result

def usage():
    stuff = ExecuteWithTimeout(do_something, 10)()
    do_something_else(stuff)
```

Another approach is to use a context manager:

```
@contextmanager
def timeout_limit(timeout):
    end = time.time() + self.timeout
    yield
    if time.time() > end:
        raise TimeoutException

def usage():
    with timeout_limit(10):
        do_stuff()
    more_things()
```

or better yet you can combine the two!

```
class TimeLimit(object):
    def __init__(self, timeout=60):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.end = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.end = time.time() + self.timeout
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.check_timeout()

    def check_timeout(self):
        if self.end and time.time() > self.end:
            raise TimeoutException

def algo():
    with TimeLimit(2) as timer:
        time.sleep(1)
        timer.check_timeout()
        time.sleep(1)
        timer.check_timeout()
```

---

update for your update:

```
timer = TimeLimit() # fails. I think because it is global
def algo():
    ...
```

Using the class as above does not help you since then the class will be a thread-level instance which puts you back to the initial problem. The problem is keeping thread-level state and so it does not matter whether you store it in a class or as function object attribute. Your functions should explicitly pass state around to the inner functions if those functions need it. You should not rely on using global state to do so:

```
def algo():
    with TimeLimit(2) as timer:
        do_stuff(timer)
        timer.check_timeout()
        do_more_stuff(timer)
        timer.check_timeout()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Will choose your answer as best, because classes allow to hold state more explicitly.

Comment: Is your algo function a view or some other utility?

Comment: It is utility function

Comment: How do I pass timer to another function?

Comment: if you need to store state between functions, you should explicitly pass it around. relying on keeping global thread-level state is not a good idea. the upper level function then should instantiate a timer and then pass it to all the inner function which require it for checking timeout.

Comment: Partly, but you did your best.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `hasattr`  guarding the *setting* of `end_time`:

```
  if not hasattr(func.info, 'end_time'):
```

```
    func.info.end_time = time.time() + seconds
```

the `end_time` is set only once for **each thread**. The threads are long-lived and serve many requests; now the absolute time limit is set once for each thread, but it is never cleared.

---

As for usefulness of this decorator, I think it is not clever; I'd say it is outright ugly. Why abuse the decorator, battle with thread-locals etc for something where a single closure would do:

```
def timelimit_checker(time_limit):
    end = time.time() + time_limit
    def checker():
        if time.time() > end:
            raise TimeoutException

    return checker

def sub_algo(check_limit):
    ...
    check_limit()
    ...

def algo():
    check_limit = timelimit_checker(60)
    ...
    check_limit()
    ...
    subalgo(check_limit)
```

Comment: I actually need separate end_time for separate thread/request? So, when two users access same page simultaneously, they have unique end_times. end_times shouldn't be shareable or what do you mean? Sorry, as I'm new in such things. I tried to remove hasattr, but, as I pointed out in 1, error raised '_thread.local' has no attribute end_time. What do you suggest?

Comment: RESPONSE to your edit. When algo is run it invokes many functions, so this should be shareable between functions. like def algo(): algo.check() sub_algo() and def sub_algo(): algo.check().

Comment: then share the timelimit checker.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've got idea finally. I like your answer, but will choose another as best, since classes seem cleaner to me.