# Kill all python main processes apart from current one

Tags: python, process

Consider the following script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

Everytime you run it, it creates a new figure within a new **python.exe** process, if you don't close the figure before. But I want to close all previous open figures (it's just an example, please no matplotlib solutions), means all previous opened processes.

This is my approach:

1. get current process ID with `os`
2. get all process IDs related to **python** with `psutil`
3. filter out current ID from all python IDs
4. kill remaining list of IDs

---

```
import os
currentId = os.getpid()

import psutil
allPyIds = [p.pid for p in psutil.process_iter() if "python" in str(p.name)]

PyIdsToKill = [x for x in allPyIds if x != currentId]
for PyId in PyIdsToKill:
    os.kill(PyId, 1)
```

It works, it closes all open python processes apart from the current one.
However I get the following error, when there are actually processes to close:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:....py", line 10, in
>   
>       for PyId in PyIdsToKill: OSError: [WinError 87] Falscher Parameter [Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]

**What is my mistake?**

---

I'm running on Windows 7 Pro:

> Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600
>   64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hard-coded the signal `1` in `os.kill`.  What is `1` supposed to be?  On Unix it would be `SIGHUP` but there is no such thing on Windows.  I suggest using the constants defined in the `signal` module, like so:

```
os.kill(PyId, signal.SIGTERM)
```

You could also consider using `signal.SIGINT`.

Comment: I got the **1** from other answers to this topic and it seemed to work. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: You're welcome.  Let this be a lesson: don't hard-code magic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use taskkill if you do not aim for cross-platform compatibility:

[Is it possible to kill a process on Windows from within Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278847/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-process-on-windows-from-within-python/6278951#6278951)

```
import os
PyIds = [int(line.split()[1]) for line in os.popen('tasklist').readlines()[3:] if line.split()[0] == "python.exe"]
PyIdsToKill = [id for id in PyIds if id != os.getpid()]
for pid in PyIdsToKill:
    os.system("taskkill /pid %i" % pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but I managed to kill all process apart from the current one by getting the pid, but when I run the code from atom,  2 processes start. so I had to match by date aswell for the one where the PID didnt match.

happy coding.

```
import re, datetime, psutil, os
print('current process: '+str(os.getpid()))
for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if str(process.pid) == str(os.getpid()):
        current_started = re.findall(r'\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}', str(process))[0]

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if "python.exe" in str(process.name):
        if str(process.pid) != str(os.getpid()):
            if str(current_started)!= re.findall(r'\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}', str(process))[0]:
                os.system("Taskkill /PID "+str(process.pid)+"")
```