# Why Python can not execute the cmd command 'tskill'?

Tags: python

In general, we can use Python to execute Windows's cmd command, for example:

```
 os.system('ipconfig')
```

but I find that `tskill` can not be executed by Python, if I use:

```
os.system('tskill 8684')
```

to kill a process by its pid, Python will show cmd's error:

```
'tskill' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

but it work well if I use cmd to run the command.

As I know `tskill.exe` is located in C:\Windows\System32, but this path is not in Python's environment variable. It is maybe the reason, but `ipconfig.exe` is also in System32, it can be executed.

So why `tskill` can not be executed by **os.system** or **subprocess.Popen**?

Comment: The message comes from the shell, not from Python.

Comment: which version of Python do you have? and what about your OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to kill a process on Windows from within Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278847/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-process-on-windows-from-within-python)

Comment: You could use taskkill instead.

Comment: @Jokab I have try taskkill, also can not run.

Comment: When you ran `tskill` direct from `cmd.exe`, did you run using Administrator access?

Comment: @Giordano Python2.7.10, Windows 7

Comment: @cdarke no, just win+R input cmd and then press enter, not using Administrator access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the root reason:

My Python is 32-bit, while My PC is Windows7 64-bit, so Python's `os.system` can not run `tskill`. If I use Python 64-bit instead, everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Use taskkill, which can do pretty much everything as tskill

But if you want to stick to tskill.exe in your scripts/code. Please run the scripts from elevated command prompts. (Right click on cmd.exe and run it as administrator)

```
os.system('c:\windows\system32\tskill.exe 8684')
```