# Close an excel file using python

Tags: python, excel

I want to close an excel file after opening it. I searched this site but I cannot get a solution. Can anyone help?

```
import os

#TODO: close the file 'myexcel.xlsx' before writing

#writing data to 'myexcel.xlsx' here

a = os.startfile('myexcel.xlsx')#open the file for reading
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What are you trying to do Depending on what you want to do, launching it as a subprocess and tracking it's process ID might be more interesting for you.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible using `startfile()`. According to the [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) documentation:

> startfile() returns as soon as the associated application is launched. There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to retrieve the application’s exit status.

You might consider using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. There are a load of options depending on what *exactly* you're trying to do at this question: [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

Comment: Can we kill the process in Windows if 'myexcel.xlsx' is opened?

Comment: Using `startfile()`? I don't believe so -- not without using `taskkill`. Maybe this would be of help there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278847/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-process-on-windows-from-within-python