# How to kill a process in Python?

Tags: python

I could issue command

```
In [41]: !killall "Expert PDF"
```

to kill a process, or encapsulate it in subprocess

```
subprocess.run("killall 'Expert PDF'",shell=True)
```

I wonder how could accomplish such a task with pure python code?

Comment: Do any of these answers help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2940858/866021

Comment: If you know command to kill the processes then you should try **os.system("<your_command>")**.

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to kill a process on Windows from within Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278847/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-process-on-windows-from-within-python)

Comment: *"Pure Python?"* No. Only the operating system can kill a process. Python must ask the operating system to kill the process using something like `subprocess`, `os.kill` or `os.system`.

Comment: @Aaron Python also has to ask the OS to create/open files, make network connections, write text to the terminal, etc. By your logic, "pure Python" can hardly do anything by itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kill process by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940858/kill-process-by-name)