# Stopping a program/application using a python script

Tags: python-3.x, windows, automation

Is there any way to terminate an application, for instance Google Chrome, using a python script or command?
Additionally, is there any python script/command to stop an application from starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Windows `taskkill` from `os.system()` inside a Python script like that:

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /f /im  process_im_goes_here.exe"")
```

Where `/f` means forcefully kill the process & `/im` is the process itself (ImageProcess) which means after that you get to specify the full path to the ImageProcess.

You can also use `tasklist` to find what processes are currently running.

Here are some taskkill usage examples:

```
taskkill /pid 1230 /pid 1241 /pid 1253
taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /im notepad.exe
taskkill /s srvmain /f /im notepad.exe
taskkill /s srvmain /u maindom\hiropln /p p@ssW23 /fi "IMAGENAME eq note*" /im \*
taskkill /s srvmain /u maindom\hiropln /fi "USERNAME ne NT*" /im \*
taskkill /f /fi "PID ge 1000" /im \*
```

Alternatively, you can use [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#kill-process-tree).

You can learn more about [taskkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb491009(v=technet.10)) here and/or python [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system).

Also, this has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278847/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-process-on-windows-from-within-python)

Hope this helped!