# How to end the task of another program in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, task, taskmanager

When you go to Task Manager and select an app and press "End Task", the program closes.
How can I do this process in python? So when the code runs, for example, the Chrome app closes.

Comment: Start by reviewing the *psutil* module. From there you will be able to identify the process you want to kill. Then study the *os* module which supports a kill function

Comment: `os.system(f'taskkill /F /PID {pid_number}')`  where pid_number is a variable containing the pid of the process you want to kill

Comment: hey sembei , good work , it worked. but some of the programs do not have a PID number. like chrome and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Clone of No.6278847: [Is it possible to kill a process on Windows from within Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278847/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-process-on-windows-from-within-python)

You can do that through the following code:

```
import os

def terminate(ProcessName):
    os.system('taskkill /im ' + ProcessName)

terminate('chrome.exe')
```

Credits: Nix

Comment: You should flag it as duplicate, not copy others' answers.

Comment: Oh alright, I am new to stack overflow, will mind that from next time. Thanks!

Comment: so , what i need to place on the "processname"? like "chrome" or "chrome.exe" or full path?

Comment: I believe just 'chrome.exe' would do, if there is an exception, try specifying the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of links related to this: (1)
[kill process using os package](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-kill-method/?ref=lbp)   (2) [Kill process using wmi package in windows](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-terminate-a-running-process-on-windows-in-python/)