# Measure memory usage taken from a process on Windows

Tags: python, windows, memory, command

I use /proc/pid/status |grep VmRSS on Linux to find out the memory usage of specific process.

Is it possible to do the same thing on Windows?
I want to perform this through Windows command window.

Another option could be to write the code in python

Comment: See [Monitor Process in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215262/monitor-process-in-python) or possibly some of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+win32+processes) others.

Comment: Got another one for you [Get memory usage of Windows processes using GetProcessMemoryInfo (via ctypes) (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578513-get-memory-usage-of-windows-processes-using-getpro/?in=lang-python).