# Create a process that runs a script until another process ends

Tags: bash

I want to monitor the power that my system needs when I run a benchmark. When the benchmark ends the monitoring process should be killed. The monitor script is written in Python.

The script which starts the monitoring script must be a Bash-script because its should be started with the same script as the Benchmark. How do I do that?

Comment: This does cover the same functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215262/monitor-process-in-python

Comment: i need to make a bash script that executes the python script as process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os, sys

if "benchmark" not in os.popen('tasklist').read():
    sys.exit()
```

Checks if a process "benchmark" is in the tasklist and if not closes the python script.
Easiest answer I think.

Comment: I now made a bash script that opend the code  that you wrote and it worked thanks!