# How can I check if a process is running in python

Tags: c#, python, process

In C#, I have:

```
Process.GetProcessesByName
```

I'm looking for something like that in Python?

Comment: If you're in Unix, an easy way is using `subprocess` to spawn `ps`. Also navigating `/proc`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Process list on Linux via Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703640/process-list-on-linux-via-python)

Comment: Could depend heavily on your OS and or Python version. Please post your specs.

Comment: i in windows and i looking for an easy way

Comment: try :
To get the processes in win platform :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632234/python-list-running-processes-64bit-windows

to get the processes in linux :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160245/which-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-list-of-running-processes-in-unix-with-python

to change the pid to name :


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189717/get-process-name-by-pid

Answer (score 1):

You can use [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) module:

> It currently supports Linux, Windows, OSX, FreeBSD, Sun Solaris both
>   32-bit and 64-bit with Python versions from 2.4 to 3.3 by using a
>   **single code base**.

First install it:

```
pip install psutil
```

Then do similar what [Process.GetProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method do:

> Creates an array of new Process components and associates them with
>   all the process resources on the local computer that share the
>   specified process name.

Code:

```
import psutil

def get_processes_by_name(name):
    return [process for process in psutil.process_iter() if process.name == name]


print(get_processes_by_name('python'))
```

Output:

```
[<psutil.Process(pid=10217, name='python') at 44007184>, 
 <psutil.Process(pid=10223, name='python') at 44007312>
]
```